# Trigger call on screen power off?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new in android. Please tell me possible way to trigger a function call when the phone goes on idle mod(Screen on to screen off)? Timer need to check this ?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this post](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) contains everything you need.

Hope this helps.